# perl while loop - will only exit the first time the condition is met

Tags: perl, while-loop

I have a script that has multiple 3 if statements, depending on which range the "cases" fall under changes the calculation that will be made. I am just starting to learn perl, I think the problem is that my last input isn't part of the while block but I can't figure out how to keep it inside without getting a curly bracket error

```
 [flata@localhost bin]$ casespacked.pl
 Please enter your name: done
 [flata@localhost bin]$ casespacked.pl
 Please enter your name: bill
 Please enter pay rate: 10
 Please enter hours worked: 20
 Please enter cases packed: 4
 Name: bill, Hours: 20, Regular Pay: 200, Bonus Pay: 20, Total Pay: 220
 Please enter your name: done
 Please enter pay rate:^C
```

the loop works as it should, and will keep producing the results I need but it won't exit correctly, only if you enter done the first time it asks for your name

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
print "Please enter your name: ";
chop( my $Name = <stdin> );
while ( $Name ne "done" ) {
    print "Please enter pay rate: ";
    chop( my $Rate = <stdin> );
    print "Please enter hours worked: ";
    chop( my $Hours = <stdin> );
    print "Please enter cases packed: ";
    chop( my $Cases = <stdin> );
    if ( $Cases >= 1 && $Cases <= 9 ) {
        $Bonus = ( $Cases * 5 );
        $Pay   = ( $Rate * $Hours );
        $Total = ( $Bonus + $Pay );
    }
    if ( $Cases >= 10 && $Cases <= 20 ) {
        $Bonus = ( $Cases * 8 );
        $Pay   = ( $Rate * $Hours );
        $Total = ( $Bonus + $Pay );
    }
    if ( $Cases >= 20 ) {
        $Bonus = ( $Cases * 10 );
        $Pay   = ( $Rate * $Hours );
        $Total = ( $Bonus + $Pay );
    }
    {
        print "Name: $Name, Hours: $Hours, Regular Pay: $Pay, Bonus Pay: $Bonus, Total Pay: $Total\n";
    }
    print "Please enter your name: ";
    chop( my $Name = <stdin> );
}
```

even if I move the print "please enter your name: "; up so its after the last if statement, it won't exit which should still be inside the while loop ? or am I not understanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `my $Name` which creates a new variable, masking the previous one. Remove the `my` from the last assignment and it will start working.

Comment: doh! I don't know why I didn't think of that. Thanks much, exactly what I was looking for

Comment: @Adam, we all do it. The more experience you have with Perl, the faster you recognize it.

Comment: @Adam: Declare `$name` separately, outside the loop `my $name;`. And use `chomp` in preference to `chop`. Also, you really shouldn't be using capital letters in local variable names. Capitals are reserved for globals by convention.

Comment: I'm sure I've seen a 'masks declaration in same scope' warning, but if I run this code with `strict` and `warnings` enabled, I don't.

Comment: @Sobrique: Because it's not in the same scope.

Answer (score 4):

Your bug is caused because your reading the subsequent `$Name` lexically scoped to the `while` block, and then it reverts to its previous value before being tested in the `while (COND)`:

```
    chop( my $Name = <stdin> );
} # $Name reverts to previous value
```

That will fix your current bug.

However, I would like to suggest a few other things:

- Always include [`use strict;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) and [`use warnings;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html) at the top of EVERY Perl script.
- Instead of trying to tie your condition directly to the while loop, just use an infinite loop that you break out of using [`last`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/last.html).
- Use [`chomp`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) instead of [`chop`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chop.html)
- Use all lowercase for variable names.  Read [`perlstyle`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlstyle.html) for specifics.
- When your conditions are linked, use `if`, `elsif`, `else` instead of a chain of independent `if`'s.  If you then reorder the conditions, you can therefore just check if something is greater than, which simplifies your logic.

The following demonstrates these and other fixes:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

while (1) {
    print "Please enter your name: ";
    chomp( my $name = <STDIN> );

    last if $name eq "done";

    print "Please enter pay rate: ";
    chomp( my $rate = <STDIN> );

    print "Please enter hours worked: ";
    chomp( my $hours = <STDIN> );

    print "Please enter cases packed: ";
    chomp( my $cases = <STDIN> );

    my $bonus;

    if ( $cases >= 20 ) {
        $bonus = $cases * 10;

    } elsif ( $cases >= 10 ) {
        $bonus = $cases * 8;

    } elsif ( $cases >= 1 ) {
        $bonus = $cases * 5;

    } else {
        warn "Invalid number of Cases: $cases\n";
        next;
    }

    my $pay   = $rate * $hours;
    my $total = $bonus + $pay;

    print "Name: $name, Hours: $hours, Regular Pay: $pay, Bonus Pay: $bonus, Total Pay: $total\n";
}
```

Comment: so this    my ($Bonus, $Pay, $Total);    is declaring those as variables?

Comment: `use strict;` requires that all variables be declared with `my` or `our`.  This is VERY helpful.  It means that if you misspell a variable, or use its type incorrectly, you will be alerted to the bug.

Comment: Nice refactoring, but I miss the "uncuddled elses" from [`perlstyle`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlstyle.html)

Comment: @Adam, Yes. `my ($Bonus, $Pay, $Total);` is the same as `(my $Bonus, my $Pay, my$Total);`, which declares those variables. More importantly, it also defines those variables, meaning it creates new variables with those names.